# How to make hotot autologin and minimize on start?

Tags: twitter, hotot

Every restart I have to click 'sign in with twitter' to log in my twitter account. I read somewhere that it is possible to log in automatically but can't find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but with the lastest version of Hotot (0.9.8 or 0.9.9, I don't remember). But this one has not been pushed in Canonical PPAs yet. They still have got the 0.9.7 version which has got the problem that you describe. Perhaps this latest version will be on Quantal PPAs, who knows ?

However, you can still use the development version or building Hotot from sources. See the [Hotot's downloads page](http://hotot.org/downloads) for further details.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I had hotot 0.9.7. I added development repo and installed 0.9.8.7. It's doing what I was looking for and works properly. Thanks.